# Hyperledger fabric query the fabcar using the user base role type Error Acces denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am using farbic CA server for register client,member,peer using the farbic node js.
While doing the registration process i am passing the role type which User,Memeber,Client. After that i do enrol which create the certificate, private,public key in wallet. I have setup the fabric network and peer has join the channel, even i have install and initiate the fabcar

My question is 
 If i register and enrol the user with role type client, i can query the fabcar chaincode, but if i register the user with role type member it's give me error.

what is difference between member vs client vs user

> channel [channel-all]: creator certificate is not valid: could not validate identity's OUs: the identity must be a client, a peer, an orderer or an admin identity to be valid, not a combination of them

Configtx.yaml file i have already mention the policy type

```
- &Org1
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org1MSP

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org1MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.avantas.com/msp

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
    #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client', 'Org1MSP.member')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client', 'Org1MSP.member')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"

    # leave this flag set to true.
    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.org1.avantas.com
          Port: 7051
```

Answer (score 0):

@fama

use below my attributes while registring admin

```
"type":"user",
"affiliation":"orgName",
"attributes":[{
"name":"admin","value":"true","ecert":true
},
```

and make corrections below

```
Policies:
    Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
    Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
    Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
```

Comment: thanks for replay, i tried this, but still same error, _channel [channelall]: creator certificate is not valid: could not validate identity's OUs: the identity must be a client, a peer, an orderer or an admin identity to be valid, not a combination of them. OUs: [[0xc00302ba70 0xc00302baa0 0xc00302bad0 0xc00302bb00]], MSP: [Org1MSP]_

Comment: did u changed policies also ?

Comment: **command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin-org1:adminpw -d'**, i am running this when i start the Fabric CA using docker container

Comment: This is ca admin iam asking org admin

Comment: "params":{ "user":"admin-org1",
                 "password":"admin-org",
                 "roletype":"user",
                 "affiliation":"org1.avantas.com",
                 "admin":"admin-org1",
                 "attributes":[{
                 "name":"admin",
                 "value":"true",
                 "ecert":"true"
                 }]

        }

Comment: could you give me the certificate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201716/discussion-between-narendranath-reddy-and-fama).

Comment: i am getting this error "No peers available to query. Errors: ["2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [channelall] creator org [Org1MSP]"]" node js